# Using double while loops to get result

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi from the code below I want to get this result

```
<s> A </s> (A_01)
<s> A </s> (A_02)
<s> A </s> (A_03)
........
<s> A </s> (A_52)
......up to
<s> Z </s> (A_01)
<s> Z </s> (A_02)
<s> Z </s> (A_03)
........
<s> Z </s> (A_52)
```

This is my try:

```
string ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def alpha (r):
 r = (string[r-1:r])+ ' '

 return (r)


def lama (o):
 o = (string[o-1:o])

 return (o)


x=1
p=1
while p<26:
 while x<53:
    c= str(x)
    y= alpha(p)

    final = '<s> ' +y +'</s> (' + lama(p) + '_' + c.zfill(2)+')'

    x = x+1

    print (final)  
 p= p+1
```

from the code above I can get only the result of A and from there it doesn't move on to B ...until Z.

Could you please take a look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a double for-loop list comprehension.

```
my_list = ['<s> {} </s> (A_{:0>2})'.format(let, num) 
           for let in list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
           for num in range(1,53)]
```